# TPM-Backed FDE not available for Dell XPS 13 9370 in the ubuntu-desktop-installer for Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: tpm

During the installation process, using `ubuntu-desktop-installer`, in the new Ubuntu 23.10 the Experimental TPM-Backed FDE is not available for my Dell XPS 13 9370.

I think my bios is configured correctly, the TPM is visible here for instance:

```
# dmesg | grep -i tpm
[    0.000000] efi: ACPI=0x3dd0b000 ACPI 2.0=0x3dd0b000 SMBIOS=0xf0000 SMBIOS 3.0=0xf0020 TPMFinalLog=0x3e3a1000 ESRT=0x3fdc1698 MEMATTR=0x3ad54098 MOKvar=0x3faca000 INITRD=0x2c92b818 TPMEventLog=0x1529a018 
[    0.008488] ACPI: TPM2 0x000000003DD46B08 000034 (v03 DELL   CBX3     00000001 AMI  00000000)
[    0.008513] ACPI: Reserving TPM2 table memory at [mem 0x3dd46b08-0x3dd46b3b]
[    0.355154] tpm_tis MSFT0101:00: 2.0 TPM (device-id 0xFC, rev-id 1)
[   19.019308] systemd[1]: systemd 253.5-1ubuntu6 running in system mode (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +APPARMOR +IMA +SMACK +SECCOMP +GCRYPT -GNUTLS +OPENSSL +ACL +BLKID +CURL +ELFUTILS +FIDO2 +IDN2 -IDN +IPTC +KMOD +LIBCRYPTSETUP +LIBFDISK +PCRE2 -PWQUALITY +P11KIT +QRENCODE +TPM2 +BZIP2 +LZ4 +XZ +ZLIB +ZSTD -BPF_FRAMEWORK -XKBCOMMON +UTMP +SYSVINIT default-hierarchy=unified)
[   19.259369] systemd[1]: systemd-pcrmachine.service - TPM2 PCR Machine ID Measurement was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionPathExists=/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/StubPcrKernelImage-4a67b082-0a4c-41cf-b6c7-440b29bb8c4f).
```

I am trying to literally turn on and off multiple options of the bios but the roundtrip between changing the BIOS settings and getting to the point of the installation in which I can see if the TPM-Backed FDE is available takes pretty much time.

Is there any clear list of requirements that I can use to correctly configure my bios apart making sure that the firmware is up-to-date (it is), the TPM is 2.0 (it is) and that the TPM is active (it is)?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution at the end.

Requirements for Dell XPS 13 9370:

- **Clear** and **Activate** TPM 2.0 in the Security Section of the BIOS configuration
- Activate Secure Boot in the Secure Boot section of the BIOS configuration
- [Turn off third party drivers during Ubuntu 23.10 setup](https://github.com/canonical/ubuntu-desktop-installer/issues/2310) to enable the option

Still it would be good to know if there is an official source for such requirements.